# External js library within Angularjs

Tags: angularjs

Is it possible to use any external js library within Angular js. If So, how to use it ? Suggest me with an example.

Comment: Generally you'd post an example you have trouble with. But yes, you can use an externaljs library within Angular. Usually, you'd wrap the important bits of that library within a Service or a Directive, or perhaps both. One thing you'll have to watch out for is crossing between angular-land and non-angular-land, and for that there's $scope.$apply()

Answer (score 0):

angularjs already included jqlite which is a short version of jquery with limited jquery api.

http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.element

maybe the link below will be useful as a start if you want to use jquery plugins with angularjs.

http://www.grobmeier.de/angular-js-binding-to-jquery-ui-datepicker-example-07092012.html